# Using CSS classes to inherit bootstrap grid system

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

This is probably a really dumb question, but here's what I need to do.

I have this html code:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
     ...stuff
</div>
```

how can I get it to look like this instead:

### index.html

```
<div class="myClass">
      ...stuff
</div>
```

### index.css

```
.myClass {
  col-xs-12
  col-md-6
  col-lg-4
}
```

I made up the syntax in the second part obviously. Point being, I don't want to clutter my HTML with CSS.

Comment: That's not possible with plain CSS. You might be able to use SCSS or similar to write up the CSS for you though, but it will still produce the _cluttered_ CSS in the end

Comment: I'm surprised no one's complained about this yet.  How is this still acceptable?

Comment: @SedkyA investigate what css is designed to do more and you'll see this is based on librarys' proclivities and nothing owing to css itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should try it with [SCSS](https://sass-lang.com/). Then you can use

```
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

.myClass {
  @extend .col-xs-12;
}
```